# How to pass props to react navigation in react native app

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using HOC to get current user details on login for each route in my react native application using `ApolloClient`.

Below is my main component **App.tsx**:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: errorLink.concat(authLink.concat(httpLink))
});

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: Feed
  },
  Upload: {
    screen: Upload
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile
  }
})

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: TabStack },
    User: { screen: UserProfile },
    Comments: { screen: Comments },
    Post: { screen: Post }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);
//Here I assign HOC to AppContainer
const RootWithSession = withSession(AppContainer);
class App extends PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (<ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <RootWithSession/>
    </ApolloProvider>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Below is HOC **withSession.tsx**:

```
export const withSession = Component=>props=>(
  <Query query={GET_CURRENT_USER}>
    {({data,loading,refetch})=>{
      if (loading) {
        return null;
      }
      console.log(data);
      return <Component {...props} refetch={refetch}/>;
    }}
  </Query>
)
```

I want to pass `refetch` function to all the components

```
<Component {...props} refetch={refetch}/>
```

How to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `navigation.setParams({ refetch })` ...

Comment: Are you sure this is react-native-navigation? This looks like react-navigation

Comment: what's wrong ? try ``console.log(refetch)`` into the wrapped components

Comment: @Auticcat am using `react-navigation-tabs` and `react-navigation-stack`

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Which file should I put this code?

Comment: @Abdelhedihlel you mean `console.log(this.props.refetch)`? It is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass `refetch` function to all Components from HOC `withSession` component using `ScreenProps` of `StackNavigator` as below:

```
export const withSession = Component=>props=>(
  <Query query={GET_CURRENT_USER}>
    {({data,loading,refetch})=>{
      if (loading) {
        return null;
      }
      if(props && props.navigation){
        //props.refetch = refetch;
        console.log(props)
        //props.navigation.refetch = refetch;
        props.navigation.setParams({refetch});
      }
      return <Component screenProps={{refetch}} {...props} refetch={refetch}/>;
    }}
  </Query>
)
```

Now, I am able to get `refetch` method using `this.props.screenProps.refetch`